# Checking User Login Status with Google

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, google-oauth, angular-ui-router

I'm using the Google OAuth2 API to manage user login for my application.  I've got most of it working correctly, to the point where it validates the Google API's session when Angular changes states.  It will successfully catch instances where the user has logged out of Google external to the application and forces them to re-authenticate before they can continue.

The issue that I'm having is when the user logs out of their Google account and then logs into another one.  I need to capture that and recheck their new Google account against our application's list of authorized users, and retrieve the correct application user token for the new user.  Right now I'm using:

```
gapi.auth.checkSessionState({ 'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'session_state': token },
                            callback);
```

I had also tried it with the `session_state` parameter set to `null`, but that didn't seem to make a difference in the functionality.  It works fine for instances where the user signs out of Google entirely external to the application, but it doesn't notice the difference in Google Accounts if the user then signs back in external to the application and tries to resume navigation without refreshing the page or otherwise resetting the GAPI JS client.

Am I missing something?  Are there any other API methods or endpoints I can query that will return a distinct result if the user has changed Google Accounts outside of my application?

Thank you.

Comment: It was suggested by a coworker that I hack around this problem by setting an interval to check the session state and try to catch them after they log out and before they log back in as someone else.  I haven't tried this yet and I suspect it will work, but it still feels hacky and I was hoping for a more robust solution...

Comment: I guess the interval ping is the best I'm going to get?